# Is proving that a mapping maps every element of the domain and is surjective sufficient to prove that it is a ring automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The ring under consideration is $R[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n]$. Shouldn't proving that a mapping $f:R[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n]\to R[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n]$ maps every element of the domain and is surjective sufficient to prove that it is an automorphism?

Motivation: A mapping is either one-one or many-one. You can't have a many-one automorphism, if the mapping is surjective, provided every element of the domain is being mapped.

For some time, as directed by others, I have been trying to prove that a mapping is an automorphism by proving the existence of the inverse mapping. Is that really necessary at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "maps every element of the domain"?

Comment: @Ayush: I agree with T. Bongers. Assuming that you mean "$f$ is defined on every element of the domain", then that is simply part of the definition of the word "*function*". [Look at the Wikipedia page on *partial* functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), in comparison.

Comment: For example, let us consider $R[x,y]$, and the mapping $f:R[x,y]\to R[x,y]$ such that $f(xy)=x$ and $f(a)=a\forall a\in R$. Then all elements in $R[x,y]$, like $x+y$ for instance, can't be mapped by such a mappping

Comment: @Ayush: What you wrote does not uniquely specify a function, so it is meaningless to talk about the properties of this supposed "mapping".

Comment: @ZevChonoles- if my question was framed as "Should proving that a function $f:R[x_{1},x_{2},\dots x_{n}]\to R[x_{1},x_{2},\dots x_{n}]$ is surjective be sufficient in proving that it is a ring automorphism?", then would the answer be in the affirmative?

Comment: @Ayush: No, a function from a ring to itself must be injective, surjective, and *also* be a ring homomorphism (don't forget this part) in order to be a ring automorphism.

Comment: Say I have proven that it is a ring homomorphism and is also surjective. Also, it is from the ring to itself. Then isn't injectivity implied? I suppose now I have put my question in a better way.

Comment: @Ayush: No, it is not. There are *some* rings where, purely coincidentally, it happens to suffice, but in general you must prove injectivity.

Comment: @ZevChonoles- terribly sorry if I'm inundating you with questions. Just one last question. $f:R\to R$. If such a homomorphism is not injective, then it is many-one. If it is many-one, then all the elements in the ring can't be mapped to...an analogy would be if there is a many-one mapping from $\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$, then all three of $1,2,3$ in the range would not be mapped to. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @Ayush: Let me give an analogy for your earlier example: if I said "*let $S=\{s,t\}$ and let $f$ be a function from $S$ to $S$ such that $f(s)=t$. What is $f(t)$?*"  the correct answer is "*that is not uniquely determined from the information given*", because there are $f$'s that satisfy my requirement that can send $t$ to either $s$ or $t$. The answer you would give, "*$t$ is not mapped*", doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Your understanding (expressed in your last comment) is true for finite situations: a surjective map $X\to X$ is automatically injective. With infinite structures however we can find surjective homomorphisms $R\to R$ that are not injective, for example the morphism on ${\bf Z}[x_1,x_2,\cdots]$ which sends $x_{i+1}\mapsto x_i$ for $i\ge1$ and sends $x_1\mapsto0$. This is obviously surjective, it is a ring endomorphism, but e.g. $0$ and $x_1$ are sent to the same element.

Comment: @anon- How is the element $x_1x_2x_3\dots \in Z[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]$ mapped to? Is defining such an element in the ring not possible? Can we only generate elements from a finite number of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you did not mention showing that $f$ is a homomorphism, which of course you need demonstrate, in addition to bijectivity.

Second, you are correct that you cannot have a many-one automorphism--that is by definition. When you say "maps every element of the domain and is surjective", I'm not sure what you mean  by the first part. To prove it's an automorphism, you must demonstrate that it is a homomorphism, that it is injective, and that it is surjective. If you are dealing with a *finite* set, it suffices to show that it is a homomorphism and that it is surjective.

Comment: Ah. "Finite set". True I should have thought about that. Thanks!